# How to submit a rails form before signup

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a task model which is associated with companies. I want companies to be able to fill up the form to post a task before they signup in the home page. Companies should get redirected to signup once they submit the form and then the task is automatically created and associated with the company.

I am using devise for the company model.

[The form should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcdCI.jpg)

Static Pages Controller:

```
def home
end
```

Tasks Controller:

```
def create
  @task = current_company.tasks.build(task_params)
  if @task.save
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def new
  @task = Task.new
end

private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :pay, files: [], course_ids: [])
  end
```

Task Model:

```
belongs_to :company
```

Company Model:

```
has_many :tasks
```

Tasks/new.html.erb:

```
<h2>Create Task</h2>
</div>
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Task Name", class: "text-field" %>
  </div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Add Description", class: "text-field", rows: 10  %>
  </div>
  <div class="space">
    <%= f.number_field :pay, placeholder: "Task Pay in USD", class: "text-field"%>
  </div>

  <div class="space">
    <label class="file-field">
        <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="space">


  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn button", style: " width: 70%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em;" %>
<% end %>
```

Static_pages/home.html.erb:

```
<div class="container-fluid container-1">
  <div class="row col-centered">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="text-align: left;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <h2 class="subtitle3"> Find Talented Freelancers</h2>
      <%= link_to "Sign Up", companysignup_path, class: "btn button", style: "width: 40%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; float: left;" %>
      <%= link_to "Log In", companylogin_path, class: "btn button", style: "width: 40%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; float: left; margin-left: 5%;" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am also interested in best practices to implement such feature with Rails.

Comment: What do you want to happen if a company adds a task but doesn't signup, should the task be saved or not? The task create method in TasksController won't work since there is no current_company if they haven't signed up yet.

Comment: One way I can think of is to use [session](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) in your tasks create method, you can put a conditional to see if the user is logged in. If they are, then create the task normally. If they are not, then store the task attributes in the session and redirect to sign up. Then, in your 'sign up' controller action, you can check if the session contains the task attributes, then you can create the record there.

Comment: Instead of putting a conditional i the taks controller I think a custom create method is better. A controller shouldn't be responsible for that.

Answer (score 1):

A very common solution is by providing "guest accounts":

```
class AddStatusToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :companies, :status, :integer, default: 0
  end
end


class Company < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  enum status: [:default, :guest, :registered]
  validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }, unless: :guest?

  def password_required?
    if guest?
      false
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

This is basically just a model with an [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) that we use to toggle the validations.

Lets alter the controller to create a guest record:

```
def create
  @company = current_company || create_guest_company
  @task = @company.tasks.build(task_params)
  if @task.save
    if @company.guest?
      redirect_to "/your/registration/path"
    else
      redirect_to @task
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private 
def create_guest_company
  company = Company.create!(status: :guest, email: "guest-#{SecureRandom.uuid}@example.com")
  sign_in company
  company
end
```

This will also require extensive changes to your registrations controller to also support updating an existing record or creating a separate route and controller to handle completing guest accounts. This is the subject of a lengthy tutorial and not a stackoverflow answer.

You will also need a recurring background task to clean up incomplete "conversions" (in the marketing sense of the term).

```
namespace :companies do
  desc "Remove guest companies more than a week old."
  task :cleanup => :environment do
    Company.guest.where("created_at < ?", 1.week.ago).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer just attempts to describe an overall approach to solve a very broad question. This is by no means a complete solution and will require quite a bit of research and finangling to get it to work with devise.

Comment: I would really question if you want to attempt this as a beginner. It might be well beyond your skill level as you will need a pretty good understanding of how devise works.